# How to Implement finish line?

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm, sprite

What I'am trying to do is once a car has crossed the finish line I would want it to say which car won the race but how could I add that to my game? The code works fine just trying to see how I could add some more features to it like a signal or some type of notification saying which car passed the finish line first.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
#Setting up our colors that we are going to use
GREEN = (20, 255, 140)
GREY = (210, 210, 210)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
BLACKWHITE =(96, 96, 96)

SCREENWIDTH = 400
SCREENHEIGHT = 500

size = (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Car Racing")
Icon = pygame.image.load("image/redca_iconr.png")
pygame.display.set_icon((Icon))
# This will be a list that will contain all the sprites we intend to use in our game.
#all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

#player
playerIMG = pygame.image.load("image/red_racecar.png")
playerX = 250
playerY = 450
playerCar_position = 0


#player2
playerIMG_two = pygame.image.load("image/greencar.png")
playerX_two = 150
playerY_two = 450
playerCar_position_two = 0


#player3
playerIMG_three = pygame.image.load("image/Orangecar.png")
playerX_three = 50
playerY_three = 450
playerCar_position_three = 0

#player4
playerIMG_four = pygame.image.load("image/yellow_car.png")
playerX_four = 200
playerY_four = 450
playerCar_position_four = 0

#Putting cars to the screen
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG, (x, y))

def player_two(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG_two, (x, y))

def player_three(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG_three, (x, y))

def player_four(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG_four, (x, y))


# Main game loop
run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
#TIP - lots of our actions take place in our while loop cause we want the function/program to run consistently
while run:
    # Drawing on Screen
    screen.fill(GREEN)
    # Draw The Road
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREY, [40, 0, 300, 500])
    # Draw Line painting on the road
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [185, 0], [185, 500], 5)
    #Finish line
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACKWHITE, [50, 50, 280, 40])
    pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [65, 70], [300, 70], 5)
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Papyrus", 45)
    text = font.render("Finish line!", 1, (150, 50, 25))
    screen.blit(text, (195 - (text.get_width() / 2), 15))
**Here is where the finish line code is at just want too add some type of notafication saying which car has crossed the finsh line first!**

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            # Number of frames per secong e.g. 60
            clock.tick(60)

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_1]:
            playerCar_position = -0.1
        if keys[pygame.K_q]:
            playerCar_position = 0.1
        if keys[pygame.K_2]:
            playerCar_position_two = -0.1
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            playerCar_position_two = 0.1
        if keys[pygame.K_3]:
            playerCar_position_three = -0.1
        if keys[pygame.K_e]:
            playerCar_position_three = 0.1

        # our functions
    playerY += playerCar_position
    playerY_two += playerCar_position_two
    playerY_three += playerCar_position_three

    player(playerX, playerY)
    player_two(playerX_two, playerY_two)
    player_three(playerX_three, playerY_three)
    player_four(playerX_four, playerY_four)


    # Refresh Screen
    pygame.display.flip()


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine the finish line is actually a rectangle.  Given the finish line goes from `[65, 70]` to `[300, 70]`, this gives us a rectangle at (65,70) that's 235 pixels wide.  Just to make things a bit safer, we can use a much wider rectangle for the line, in case a car is moving many pixels in an update... just so it can't "jump" the line without ever entering it.

```
finish_line_rect = pygame.Rect( 65,70, 235,32 )           # but 32 pixels wide
```

Then when each car moves, you can use `pygame.Rect.collidepoint()` with the `x,y` of each car to see if it overlaps with the `finish_line_rect`.

For example:

```
# Move the Players' cars 
playerY += playerCar_position
playerY_two += playerCar_position_two
playerY_three += playerCar_position_three

# Draw the Players' cars
player(playerX, playerY)
player_two(playerX_two, playerY_two)
player_three(playerX_three, playerY_three)
player_four(playerX_four, playerY_four)

# Did anyone cross the line?
if ( finish_line_rect.collidepoint( playerX, playerY ) ):
    print( "Player (one) has crossed into finish rectangle" )
if ( finish_line_rect.collidepoint( playerX_two, playerY_two ) ):
    print( "Player two has crossed into finish rectangle" )
# ETC.
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I think you should create a "car" class as to not duplicate so much code and make it easier to work with. Regarding the finish line, I would do the following:

```
#Create an array with all cars X value
CarPositions = [Car1_x, Car2_x, Car3_x, Car4_x]

#Define X value of Finishline
Finishline = 600

def CheckPosition(CarPositions, Finishline):
    for i in range(len(CarPositions)):
       if CarPositions[i] >= Finishline:
          return CarPositions[i]
```

You should have your array of X positions in numerical order i.e. Car 1 is before Car 2 in the array. That way the i in the for loop represents which number car has passed.